# Making hidden HTML text bold when it is displayed

Tags: html, css

On my webpage I have text that is in a hidden field(`input type="hidden"`). When I display the text, I would like it to be bold so it stands out. 
Can this be done with CSS or any other way? I have already tried `style="font-weight: bold;"` and it doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: Is there some event that makes the hidden text appear?

Comment: Try `style="font-weight: 700;"`

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong. It's as simple as this: http://jsfiddle.net/7HqQW/2/

Comment: Also, are you setting a specific font-family? I've noticed certains fonts don't bold in Chrome.

Comment: The text is set to visible by a javascript callback.

Comment: Can you post the code for that event?

Comment: `<input type="hidden">` are never displayed. You could use a text field with the property disabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="Hello" />
```

**CSS:**

```
#myInput
{
    display:none;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function ShowInput()
{
    document.getElementById("myInput").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("myInput").style.fontWeight="bold";
}
```

Check it http://jsfiddle.net/LvaFS/

Comment: Since the normal status is display:none, it can be already bold; there is no difference. Then, you only need to change the display to block in the function